# How to check if a range of cells all have a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Firstly, I am learning excel and am still a novice so I apologize that I do not know the best function to start the formula, but I believe it is a IF or SEARCH.

What I want to accomplish:
If a range of **ALL** of a value (always a number or percent) then return True, if **even one cell** in the range is blank then return False.

So if i were to write the formula verbally I would say:

```
If range A1:A5 **all** contain a value of any kind, return true, **if all do not** contain a value, return false.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this standard formula for *'a value of any kind'*,

```
=counta(a1:a5)=5
```

Alternate,

```
=not(countblank(a1:a5))
```

To check specifically for five numbers,

```
=count(a1:a5)=5
```

Comment: Oh, that is a clever take on it! That suits my needs. Thank you :)

- I can confirm this just worked. I will mark it as the answer as soon as the site allows me to.

Comment: If you want to not have to manually enter the number of cells in your range (if you're using a named dynamic range, for example), try `=count(a1:a5)=rows(a1:a5)*columns(a1:a5)`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A3:G3)=0
```

Though this will accept text instead of a number or percentage.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try :)

Comment: COUNTBLANK also counts zero-length strings (e.g. `""`) sometimes left as a result from a formula as blanks so this is a valid alternative depending on the data layout.